# Finding the Thevenin equivalent resistance in given circuit

Tags: resistance, thevenin

I tried finding the equivalent resistance (between the nodes A&B) for the given circuit, however I can't seem to get it right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZJHrS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The equivalent voltage is 0, that I was able to calculate, but the answer for resistance is Rt = 16, which I'm not sure how to find.

Comment: First redraw the circuit with all voltage and current sources replaced by their equivalent source resistances. Then, once it's all resistances, simplify. If you get stuck, post the schematic you've got so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to just do your homework for you.  However, consider what the impedance of a voltage source and a current source are.  Since you're only looking for the impedance, voltage and current offsets don't matter.  Replace the voltage sources with shorts and the current sources with opens.

After you redraw the circuit as above, it comes down to solving a resistor mesh.  Look for series and parallel resistances to combine, and proceed the usual way to solve a mesh.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xjWNDrK.png that I did, but one thing is bothering me, do the bottom three form a "star" or Y (not sure how it's called in English)?

Comment: @Ale: Show your work in the question, not some link in a comment.  There are obvious simplifications that can be performed in what you linked to.